# Is "volatile" needed within methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have read that you should use `volatile` when a thread accesses a variable to make sure that the threads see the correct value, but does that also apply when the variable is used within a method?

Example code:

```
public class Limiter
{
    int max = 0;

    public synchronized void doSomething()
    {
         max++;
         if(max < 10)
             System.out.println("Work");

         System.out.println(max);
    }

}
```

Is it safe to assume that if a multiple thread calls `doSomething`, then `max` will be set to the same state as when the previous Thread called the method?

Because `doSomething()` is synchronized, I know that only a single thread can modify `max`, but what happens when the next thread calls it? Can `max` be a different value because it doesn't use `volatile`? Or is it safe because the "Limiter" instance modifies it itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`volatile` is part of the *declaration* of a field, not part of its *use*. It would make no sense to declare a local variable as volatile, as local variables won't be seen by different threads.

In your case, you're fine so long as no code in non-synchronized methods accesses `max` - the memory model basically makes sure that so long as all code acquires/releases the same monitor "guarding" a variable, all threads will see a consistent sequence of values. (Aside from anything else, the fact that the threads each have to acquire the monitor before accessing the value means only one thread will be able to access the value at a time - you could write a total ordering of "thread X had the monitor at time t0-t1, thread Y had the monitor at time t4-t5" etc.)

Comment: `local variables won't be seen by different threads` - What if you close over a local variable in a callback?

Comment: @ig-dev: Closing over local variables requires that those are effectively final, doesn't it? (I don't know whether there have been changes since I was more regularly involved in Java...)

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that you should use volatile when a thread accesses a variable to make sure that the threads see the correct value, but does that also apply when the variable is used within a method?

This is inaccurate in a number of respects<sup>*</sup>.

Firstly: `volatile` can only be used on fields.  It cannot be used on other kinds of variables; i.e. local variables or parameters.  (Reason: it would be pointless, because the other kinds of variable are only ever visible to one thread.)

Secondly: `volatile` semantics apply whether or not you are calling from a method.

Thirdly: `volatile` is an *alternative* to using `synchronized` methods (or blocks).  But the correct use of `synchronized` typically conditional on *all* accesses and updates being performed using the synchronization construct.  Any non-synchronized accesses or updates *could* render the program (as a whole) incorrect.

Finally: `volatile` means that accesses to the field will see the *latest* value of the field's value.  This is not sufficient to guarantee *correctness*.  For example:

```
public Counter {
    private volatile int count;

    public void increment() {
        // This is NOT correct.
        count++;
    }
}
```

The reason that the above example is incorrect is that `count++` is not atomic.  It actually means (literally) `count = count + 1`, and another thread could change `count` in between the current thread accessing it and writing back the updated value.  This would result in occasional lost increments.

It is easy to see that a version of your code that declared `max` as `volatile` and got rid of the `synchronized` keyword would be incorrect for exactly the same reason.  Your current version is more correct in that respect.  However, it is still not entirely correct, because there is nothing stopping some other class (in the same package) from accessing or updating  `max`.  If that was done in a different thread, you'd have a potential concurrency issue ... in addition to the leaky abstraction.

---

So, to answer your questions:

> Is it safe to assume that if a multiple thread calls doSomething, then max will be set to the same state as when the previous Thread called the method?

Not entirely, because of the leaky abstraction.  (Declaring `max` to be private fixes this.)

> Because doSomething() is synchronized, I know that only a single thread can modify max, but what happens when the next thread calls it?

The `synchronized` block ensures that the next thread that synchronizes on the same object will see those updates.  (How this is achieved is platform specific ...)

> Can max be a different value because it doesn't use volatile?

No ... modulo the leaky abstraction problem.

> Or is it safe because the "Limiter" instance modifies it itself?

That fact is *not relevant* to that thread-safety / correctness of this code.  It is synchronization that matters, not self-modification.

---

<sup>* At least, your summary of what you have understood by what you have read is inaccurate.  For all we know, the original text that you read may be correct.</sup>

---

**UPDATE**

> The part I read was talking about fields (as in variables accessible by the thread). Sorry for the confusion. What I wanted to know was if it also applied to all variables used by a method in an object called by a thread.

This applies to all fields of the object that the thread reads and/or writes are covered by the synchronized region.  And indeed, it applies to the fields of other objects, and elements of arrays read / written in the region.  (It is "moot" for variables that are not fields, because no other thread can see them.)

However, the caveat is that it ONLY applies with respect to the synchronization point.  If the second thread does not synchronize properly, all bets are off.

Comment: The part I read was talking about fields (as in variables accessible by the thread). Sorry for the confusion. What I wanted to know was if it also applied to all variables used by a method in an object called by a thread.